# How to access a server file from PyScript?

Tags: file, pyscript

I have a PyScript running on the home.html page of a website, and within the script I'd like to read some information from a file stored in same directory as the home.html page but I always get error "Host is unreachable".
I expect to be able to read information from a file stored in same directory as my home.html page containing the script.

I am trying the following:

```
url='<my file full URL here>'
req = urllib.request.Request(url=url)            
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req,timeout=120)
data=response.read().decode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 1):

PyScript doesn't play well (actually, doesn't play at all) with most existing Python libraries that handle HTTP requests (requests, httpx, urllib). Take a look at the PyScript documentation on HTTP requests [here](https://docs.pyscript.net/latest/guides/http-requests.html) for guidance. It's a great walk-through on making HTTP requests in PyScript using `pyfetch`, a Python wrapper of the JavaScript `fetch` api.

One quick warning about the documentation. Like PyScript itself, the documentation is a work in progress. In the link above, there's a reference to the `py-env` tag. That has been deprecated and it doesn't look like they've updated that part of the documentation. The functions of the `py-env` tag have been subsumed in the `py-config` tag. More on that [here.](https://docs.pyscript.net/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html#the-py-config-tag)

UPDATE:
As a framework under development, PyScript is going to be a moving target for a while. Specific to your case, the documentation on http-requests ([How to make HTTP requests using PyScript](https://docs.pyscript.net/latest/guides/http-requests.html)) was actually updated just this morning (11/8/2022). I'll refer you to that page for the code. One very important note, however. The code examples are written as though they are being run in an updated local development environment. When you point to the remote PyScript version to use, it matters which one you select. Your code points to `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />`
, which is perfectly reasonable -- it is, after all, the suggested release. The code example in the documentation, however, will not work with 'latest'. It will, however, work with 'unstable' (`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/unstable/pyscript.css" />`). When running this code using the 'unstable' release, it also appears that you have to run it in a live server. The point is workable solutions are going to be hit and miss for a while. What works today may not work next week.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried this but getting "500: Internal Server Error".

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post everything between the py-script tags and between the py-config tags.

Comment: Posting that as answer below.